# How to pick specific results from a loop in python + problem with print vs return

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I defined a function that prints multiple values as lists, I've written it in such a way that the first value in the list is x and the other is the result of a specific equation.

The first problem is that when I use return instead of print(), I am only getting the first iteration of the loop, unlike print() which prints everything (which is what I want)

Second, I want to pick certain results that come from this loop function:

I want to pick the results with the smallest value of the second item in the list. For example in [12, 2], [13, 1], [14, 5], I want to write a function that returns or prints [13, 1] as 1 is the smallest. The first term in the list is just for observation.

I also want to make a list or just return values of the top 10 items with the smallest second value.

```
def temporary3(ratio,x,y):
  results = [] 
  for x in range(1,x):
    results.append(abs((1200*math.log((2**(x/y)),2)-(1200*math.log(ratio,2))))) 
  return results
def intApprox(ratio,x):
  return min(temporary3(ratio,x,x))
def tempFinder(ratio):
  list1 = []
  for x in range(12,61,1):
    list1.append(intApprox(ratio,x))
    print([x,round(intApprox(ratio,x),3)])
```

Then we can try the code:

```
tempFinder(5/4)
```

We get something like: [image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please [don't post images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

> "return statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine"

Your for loop stops after the return statement, it doesn't do the second execution because a return statement kills the loop and the function running it.